# GLUI problem when using cocos2d OpenGL

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Has anyone come across this problem when building with cocos2d (OpenGL library for iPhone 2D games)?

```
"glui/GL/glui.h" file is not found
gluOrtho2D was not declared
GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT was not declared.
```

There seems to be very little info on GLUI for iPhone on the web.  I am new to OpenGL, so appreciate the help!  I have included OpenGLES CoreGraphics libraries, even tried adding linker flag "-framework GLUI" but to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this working by following a different tutorial.  The Monocles tutorial is outdated since it uses cocos2d v.0.7.2.

There has been significant change to cocos2d v.0.8, which comes pre-packaged with an easy to use XCode Project Template, and in v.0.9, libraries filenames have been further improved with the CC prefix to avoid namespace collision.  I would recommend this tutorial instead:

http://iphonedev.net/2009/07/12/cocos2d-example-box2d/

Also found this to be useful.
http://www.mycodestudio.com/blog/2009/12/06/cocos2dpt1/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by

- removing cocos2d's external/Box2d/Testbed directory
- adding GLUI.framework from /Library/Frameworks/GLUI.framework (and setting the framework search path)

It compiles successfully, but dies on launching in simulator with this error, which seems unrelated to the question above.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```